# Why would this give a Use of uninitialised value of size 8

Tags: c++, valgrind

In my code I have a class named `membrane` with a function named `exciteMod()`, a function named `decide()` and a variable named `delta_U`. The first line of `exciteMod()` is `this->delta_U = 0`. In `decide()` I have an exponent of `-delta_U` (`exp(-this->delta_U)`). which cause an error Use of uninitialised value of size 8. The only place where I call `decide()` is inside of `exciteMod()`. What might cause this? I don't have any error about `delta_U` which is generated in valgrind.

Relevant segment of the code:

```cpp
    void membrane::exciteMod(){
      this->delta_U = 0;
      /* Do some stuff which does not directly affect this->delta_U*/
      std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> bit = this->beads.begin();
      while (bit != this->nead.end()){
        std::tr1::shared_ptr<bead> b = *bit++;
        //calculate the doubles U and nextU on b, nothing here gives a warning in valgrind,     anyhow U and nextU on b are always defined
       this->delta_U += (b->nextU - b->U);
      }
      decide();
    }
    
    void membrane::decide(){
      double r = P.r.ran3() // the random function from numerical recepies
      double f = - this->delta_U;
      if (r > exp(f)){ //this gives the warning even though delta_U is valid
        /*stuff*/
      }
    }
```

This is the warning:

```
> ==467==    Use of uninitialised value of size 8  
> ==467==    at 0x300B00D75D: __ieee754_exp (in /lib64/libm-2.5.so)  
> ==467==    by 0x300B022FA3: exp (in /lib64/libm-2.5.so)  
> ==467==    by 0x40BB9A: membrane::decide() (membrane.cpp:813)  
> ==467==    by 0x40EBB1: membrane::exciteMod() (membrane.cpp:639)  
> ==467==    by 0x413994: membrane::MCstep(int) (membrane.cpp:486)  
> ==467==    by 0x402767: main (main.cpp:14)
```

Comment: By the way, you don't need the `this->` syntax to access member variables within a member function.  Access them directly: `delta_u = 0;`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The most likely cause of uninitialized value is that at least one of `b->nextU` or `b->U` that you are adding to `delta_U` is itself uninitialized. That is:

```
foo = 0;
foo += some_uninitialized_value;
if (foo)  // Valgrind warns here
```

You would like Valgrind to report when foo becomes uninitialized. Unfortunately, doing so  produces too many "false positive" warnings to be practical.

You can insert into your loop calls to `VALGRIND_CHECK_MEM_IS_DEFINED` (see [Valgrind user manual](http://valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.value)), and Valgrind will signal the exact moment when `delta_U` becomes undefined.

Comment: Yea I have found this late last night. What I don't understand is why this is the place the error is thrown and previously.

Answer (score 0):

lets say you have t number of values needed to be stored. then use this:

```
int *p = (int *) malloc(t*(sizeof(int)+1));
memset(p,0,t*(sizeof(int)+1));
```