# Use of uninitialised value of size 8. C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks, valgrind

These are few snippets of where I think the problem lies (a lot of code otherwise):

```
//to insert the course by name and number into the hash table
int Table::insert(Course & c) {
  return insertByName(c) - insertByNumber(c); //return 0 for success
}


//to insert the course by the name into the hash table
int Table::insertByName(Course & c) {
  int index;
  char *name;

  c.getName(name); //copy the name of the course
  index = hashFunc(name); //get the index for the name
  //insert the course by the index of the name at head
  if (table[index] == NULL) { ///////////////////////////// LINE: 144
      table[index] = new node;
      table[index]->course.copy(c);
      table[index]->next = NULL;
  } else {
      node * temp = new node;
      temp->course.copy(c);
      temp->next = table[index];
      table[index] = temp;
  }
  return 1;
}



//to insert the course by the number into the hash table
  int Table::insertByNumber(Course & c) {
  int index;
  char *number;

  c.getNumber(number); //copy the number of the course
  index = hashFunc(number); //get the index for the number

  //insert the course by the index of the name at head
  if (table[index] == NULL) { ///////////////////////////// LINE: 167
      table[index] = new node;
      table[index]->course.copy(c);
      table[index]->next = NULL;
  } else {
      node * temp = new node;
      temp->course.copy(c);
      temp->next = table[index];
      table[index] = temp;
  }
  return 1;
}
```

**UPDATE:** Here is `Course::getName()` and `Course::getNumber()`:

```
//to copy the name of the course to the passed array
int Course::getName(char *& arr) {
  arr = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
  strcpy(arr, name);
  return 1;
}


//to copy the number of the course to the passed array
int Course::getNumber(char *& arr) {
  arr = new char[strlen(number) + 1];
  strcpy(arr, number);
  return 1;
}
```

**HERE IS A DETAILED ERROR MESSAGE (Valgrind):**

> ```
> --24010-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
> --24010--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so ..
> --24010--   .. CRC mismatch (computed ef2bc4a1 wanted 12987a55)
> --24010--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so ..
> --24010--   .. CRC is valid
> --24010-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
> --24010--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux ..
> --24010--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 4f1eed43 wanted a323a3ab)
> --24010--    object doesn't have a symbol table
> --24010--    object doesn't have a dynamic symbol table
> --24010-- Scheduler: using generic scheduler lock implementation.
> --24010-- Reading suppressions file: /usr/lib/valgrind/default.supp
> ==24010== embedded gdbserver: reading from /tmp/vgdb-pipe-from-vgdb-to-24010-by-bad6-on-???
> ==24010== embedded gdbserver: writing to   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-to-vgdb-from-24010-by-bad6-on-???
> ==24010== embedded gdbserver: shared mem   /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-24010-by-bad6-on-???
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== TO CONTROL THIS PROCESS USING vgdb (which you probably
> ==24010== don't want to do, unless you know exactly what you're doing,
> ==24010== or are doing some strange experiment):
> ==24010==   /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=24010 ...command...
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== TO DEBUG THIS PROCESS USING GDB: start GDB like this
> ==24010==   /path/to/gdb ./a.out
> ==24010== and then give GDB the following command
> ==24010==   target remote | /usr/lib/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=24010
> ==24010== --pid is optional if only one valgrind process is running
> ==24010== 
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x4019ca0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strlen) redirected to 0x380764b1 (???)
> --24010-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
> --24010--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so ..
> --24010--   .. CRC mismatch (computed fc68135e wanted 45f5e986)
> --24010--    object doesn't have a symbol table
> --24010-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
> --24010--   Considering /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so ..
> --24010--   .. CRC mismatch (computed ae683f7e wanted 08c06df2)
> --24010--    object doesn't have a symbol table
> ==24010== WARNING: new redirection conflicts with existing -- ignoring it
> --24010--     old: 0x04019ca0 (strlen              ) R-> (0000.0) 0x380764b1 ???
> --24010--     new: 0x04019ca0 (strlen              ) R-> (2007.0) 0x04c2e1a0 strlen
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x4019a50 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:index) redirected to 0x4c2dd50 (index)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x4019c70 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:strcmp) redirected to 0x4c2f2f0 (strcmp)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x401a9c0 (ld-linux-x86-64.so.2:mempcpy) redirected to 0x4c31da0 (mempcpy)
> --24010-- Reading syms from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
> --24010--   Considering /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 ..
> --24010--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 5ce96d3c wanted bf86fabd)
> --24010--    object doesn't have a symbol table
> --24010-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
> --24010--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 ..
> --24010--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 6116126e wanted 54e3f1f2)
> --24010--    object doesn't have a symbol table
> --24010-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
> --24010--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so ..
> --24010--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 600bae51 wanted b4d0580d)
> --24010--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so ..
> --24010--   .. CRC is valid
> --24010-- Reading syms from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so
> --24010--   Considering /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so ..
> --24010--   .. CRC mismatch (computed 0fbb5cf0 wanted cac31e3b)
> --24010--   Considering /usr/lib/debug/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.19.so ..
> --24010--   .. CRC is valid
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53ddd60 (libc.so.6:strcasecmp) redirected to 0x4a25720 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53e0050 (libc.so.6:strncasecmp) redirected to 0x4a25720 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53dd530 (libc.so.6:memcpy@GLIBC_2.2.5) redirected to 0x4a25720 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53db7c0 (libc.so.6:rindex) redirected to 0x4c2da30 (rindex)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53d9ac0 (libc.so.6:strlen) redirected to 0x4c2e0e0 (strlen)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53dcfa0 (libc.so.6:__GI_memcmp) redirected to 0x4c30b80 (__GI_memcmp)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53d8070 (libc.so.6:strcmp) redirected to 0x4a25720 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53e8d20 (libc.so.6:__strcmp_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c2f1b0 (strcmp)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x4e95ea0 (libstdc++.so.6:operator new[](unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c2b790 (operator new[](unsigned long))
> # How many courses would you like to enter? 1
> - Please enter the name of the course: a
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53d9500 (libc.so.6:strcpy) redirected to 0x4a25720 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53edb90 (libc.so.6:__strcpy_sse2_unaligned) redirected to 0x4c2e1c0 (strcpy)
> - Please enter the number of the course: a
> - Please enter the section of the course: 
> - Please enter the time of the course: a
> - Please enter the CRN of the course: a
> - Please enter the description of the course: a
> ===============================================================
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x4e94120 (libstdc++.so.6:operator delete[](void*)) redirected to 0x4c2c7d0 (operator delete[](void*))
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x40236F: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:144)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x4e95d90 (libstdc++.so.6:operator new(unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c2b070 (operator new(unsigned long))
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4023A1: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:145)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4023B9: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:146)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4023E0: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:147)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4024E3: Table::insertByNumber(Course&) (Table.cpp:167)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DF2: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4025A2: Table::insertByNumber(Course&) (Table.cpp:174)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DF2: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4025C6: Table::insertByNumber(Course&) (Table.cpp:175)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DF2: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x4e940f0 (libstdc++.so.6:operator delete(void*)) redirected to 0x4c2c250 (operator delete(void*))
> --24010-- REDIR: 0x53d3df0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2bd80 (free)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==24010==     in use at exit: 4 bytes in 2 blocks
> ==24010==   total heap usage: 29 allocs, 27 frees, 456 bytes allocated
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== Searching for pointers to 2 not-freed blocks
> ==24010== Checked 194,168 bytes
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==24010==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 2 blocks
> ==24010==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==24010==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==24010==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==24010==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==24010== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
> ==24010== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 1 errors in context 1 of 7:
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4025C6: Table::insertByNumber(Course&) (Table.cpp:175)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DF2: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 1 errors in context 2 of 7:
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4025A2: Table::insertByNumber(Course&) (Table.cpp:174)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DF2: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 1 errors in context 3 of 7:
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4024E3: Table::insertByNumber(Course&) (Table.cpp:167)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DF2: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 1 errors in context 4 of 7:
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4023E0: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:147)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 1 errors in context 5 of 7:
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4023B9: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:146)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 1 errors in context 6 of 7:
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x4023A1: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:145)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== 1 errors in context 7 of 7:
> ==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
> ==24010==    at 0x40236F: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:144)
> ==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
> ==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
> ==24010== 
> ==24010== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
> ```

Does anyone have an idea of what the error is about? I hope someone would "understand" the problem with this little amount of information, because I thought it would be easier since I have more than 1000 lines of code separated into different header files and .cpp files.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think the error is in the snippet you shared. Refer you this link for some insight into the error: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7102142/2555668

Comment: Please post the code of `Course::getName()` and `Course::getNumber()`. Also, can you mark the line numbers? In particular, lines 144 and 167.

Comment: @AntonSavin I added them

Comment: Well done for using valgrind.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (table[index] == NULL) { ///////////////////////////// LINE: 144
```

relates to

```
==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24010==    at 0x40236F: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:144)
==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
==24010==
```

It either thinks that table array was not fully initialized, so the value in Table might not be NULL, or it may possibly be `Index` is out of range.

```
--24010-- REDIR: 0x4e95d90 (libstdc++.so.6:operator new(unsigned long)) redirected to 0x4c2b070 (operator new(unsigned long))
==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24010==    at 0x4023A1: Table::insertByName(Course&) (Table.cpp:145)
==24010==    by 0x401DDD: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)

/*145*/  table[index] = new node;
```

Its difficult to see what is causing the complaint here - if `node` has a constructor, this may have an error, otherwise table[index] is being initialized, and this may be a mis-report

Comment: Actually you are right **AGAIN**!!!! I solved one problem that existed, but there is still something wrong related to initialization. I'll keep looking for it. I have a strong feeling that it is the copy constructor for table (since I pass it by value within the program). Would it be helpful if I post it here?

Comment: Also, I don't think it is an out of bound problem, because I used gdb and it doesn't seg-fault. And node doesn't have a constructor (it is a struct).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @mksteve, I managed to know where to look exactly and I found that it was not an **initialization problem**!!! What I did wrong was that I didn't deallocate the memory used to for the temp array used inside `Course::getName()` and `Course::getNumber()`.

**Here is the solution:**

```
 //to insert the course by the name into the hash table
int Table::insertByName(Course & c) {
  int index;
  char *name;

  c.getName(name); //copy the name of the course
  index = hashFunc(name); //get the index for the name
  //insert the course by the index of the name at head
  if (table[index] == NULL) { ///////////////////////////// LINE: 144
      table[index] = new node;
      table[index]->course.copy(c);
      table[index]->next = NULL;
  } else {
      node * temp = new node;
      temp->course.copy(c);
      temp->next = table[index];
      table[index] = temp;
  }
  delete[] name; ///////////////////////////////////THAT FIXED THE BUG
  return 1;
}



//to insert the course by the number into the hash table
  int Table::insertByNumber(Course & c) {
  int index;
  char *number;

  c.getNumber(number); //copy the number of the course
  index = hashFunc(number); //get the index for the number

  //insert the course by the index of the name at head
  if (table[index] == NULL) { ///////////////////////////// LINE: 167
      table[index] = new node;
      table[index]->course.copy(c);
      table[index]->next = NULL;
  } else {
      node * temp = new node;
      temp->course.copy(c);
      temp->next = table[index];
      table[index] = temp;
  }
  delete[] number; ///////////////////////////////////THAT FIXED THE BUG
  return 1;
}
```

Thank you all for your support. I think the problem was so clear, but I wasn't looking at the right place. I also think that the error message was a little bizarre, don't you think. Anyway, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

I don't think this analysis is correct, as I mis-read the question.  But I think I helped the OP, with this answer whilst re-working.

As such I have un-deleted - in case it helps other people.

The complaint is

```
int Course::getName(char *& arr) {
  arr = new char[strlen(name) + 1];
  strcpy(arr, name);
  return 1;
}
```

That the global/member `name`
Does not yet have a value.  This would be better as a parameter.
Similar issue in number

```
==24010== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==24010==    at 0x4025C6: Table::insertByNumber(Course&) (Table.cpp:175)
==24010==    by 0x401DF2: Table::insert(Course&) (Table.cpp:56)
==24010==    by 0x40144C: main (main.cpp:39)
```

The display describes a call stack.

```
main => Table::insert => Table::insertByNumber
```

where it sees an issue.  So line 175 of Table.cpp is the line of the file which causes this.

Looking at `arr`, I can see it is only used on the left, and appears to have a value.  That means the thing  on the right (`name` or `number`) must be the cause.

The request for line numbers in comments was important, because it helps identify from possible causes.